# Augmented Reality with real time object

Tags: augmented-reality, layer, vuforia

Now I have an requirement in Augmented Reality, I suppose to detect the live object(pen/marker) then I have play some interactive content.

I need a suggestion/advise from you is to recommend the appropriate SDK to develop this app.

I used Vuforia for normal/simple AR app but this is involved the real time object detection.

Friends, kindly suggest me the SDK to meet the requirement.

-Murali Krishnan

Comment: [metaio](http://www.metaio.com/products/sdk/) can do object-based tracking.

Comment: Vuforia does it also. In TargetManager you can also upload 3d objects, not only images. The detection is real time. On the other hand you can use, like ashatte said, Metaio/Junaio. What issues did you encounter while trying to use Vuforia?

Comment: I am not referring 3D object but the real pen. Here I dont want to wrap any printed images on the pen/market.

Comment: For example, I have a market pen which i want to detect using AR. Once it is detected then I want to play a video

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a cylinder object. you would need to create a different object, for each pen style you would want as a trackable.

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/creating-cylinder-target

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ashatte, you should have a look at metaios sdk.

You are looking for 3d Markerless tracking. The sdk is very good for this.

Comment: Thanks Nad, yes I also preferred metaios for this requirement.